# Script to look at contents of text document and add text to beginning of each line

Tags: text, document, addition

I am just looking for a quick way to look at the contents of a text document and then add text  to the beginning of each line. Every line will get the same text at the beginning. Maybe an easy script to do this. Any ideas or suggestions. Thanks

Comment: A little more info please. What do you mean by script? Is it a bash, do you have unix binutils available for scripting? Should it be cross-platform with python/php/perl?

Comment: I have a text file with hundreds of lines. I need to insert text at the beginning of each of these lines. Trying to figure out a way to add this text to each line within the text document without having to do each line manually.

Comment: Does the answer below help you? If not, what OS are you running and what tools do you have available? SED should be standard in most Linux distributions but you could get it for Win as well.

Comment: Sill I think **sed** is the way to go. Do you have any scripting languages like python already installed?

Comment: No, no scripting languages installed. So would sed just work in a batch file?

Comment: I'm no windows user but I guess everything you can use from a terminal window will also work from a batchfile. So you would first have to install sed and then for every file you wanted to edit you would add a line like in my answer to the batch file. You will probably have to call something like "C:\programs\sed.exe" or whatever instead of just "sed" but the rest remains the same.

Comment: Just give it a try, I'll be here to help you out if there are some more problems.

Comment: I am fairly new to making batch scripts so I am having some trouble

Comment: Get sed (complete package) from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files//sed/4.2.1/sed-4.2.1-setup.exe/download and try to run it manually from a cmd window first before attempting to batch it. Does this work?

Comment: Once i have it downloaded, do i just try try what you have in the answer below in a cmd window? or am i missing something?

Comment: You should be fine just doing that, just replace FILENAME with the exact location of the file you're trying to edit and sed with the execat path to sed.exe. Of course you have to install it first after downloading, but I assume that's what you meant. ;)

Comment: something like this?  C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\sed -i 's/^/test/' C:\SCRIPTS.txt

Comment: I guess so, you might have to put quotation marks (") around the command or you might run into trouble with the spaces. Maybe you also need to add .exe extension but I'm not sure. Otherwise it's looking fine to me. I'll be off to football practice, back in about two hours.

Comment: OK im a little closer....now i am getting an error..."sed.exe: -e expression #1 , char #1: unknown command"

Comment: Strange... only thing I could think of is maybe using doublequotes instead of singles. Don't know how Windows deals with that. Maybe have a look at the documentation.

Comment: It would mean it doesn't know the 's' command which is the first char of the first (only) expression. The info above is all outputyou get? If I try a non existent command (e.g. capital S) I get: **sed: -e expression #1,char 1: unknown command: `S'** Did you spell everything correctly? Oh boy, this whole scripting stuff is so much more comfortable on Linux anyway.

Answer (score 2):

One of the easist ways would be using **sed** (stream editor) which can read from file or stdin. It does so on a line-by-line basis and can apply modification of the content either for the whole file or for specific sub-ranges. This is what you will want to do:

```
sed -i 's/^/TEXT/' FILENAME
```

The **-i** options tells sed to edit the file "in place", meaning it's directly written into the file instead of going to stdout. The original file is overwritten. If you want to keep the original data just ommit this option and pipe the output into a different file by appending **> NEWFILE** to the commandline above.

The **s** command in sed is search/replace. It will, on each line, replace the first occurance of the first pattern with the second pattern. You can add **g** at the end to replace every occurance of the first pattern in any line but since you're matching the beginning of the line this is not particullary useful here.

The first pattern here is **^** which is a reserved character in regular expressions meaning the beginning of the line. So it will just add the second pattern **TEXT** before any other text appears.

Of course you can call that from a script if you have to batch-process many files in that way. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it fairly cross plattform you could write a short and simple python script.

```
inputFile = open("fileNameInput")
outputFile = open("fileNameOutput", "w")

for inputLine in inputFile:
    outputFile.write("your text" + inputLine + "\n")

inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can easily be done in VB Script, too. If you're looking for a native Windows solution, using this little script snippet:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set inputFile =  FSO.OpenTextFile("inputFilePath", ForReading)
Set outputFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("outputFilePath", ForWriting)

Do Until inputFile.AtEndOfStream

        outputFile.Write("Your Text" & inputFile.ReadLine)

Loop

inputFile.Close
outputFile.Close
```